# React Formik Yup validation on callback error message not synchronous

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, formik, yup

I created an input field component in react using formik and yup for validation.

what I am doing is when error came from input field component disable submit button.

I get the typed data onchange but error message from input field is not synchronous like on empty it will show (name required) it showing in UI correctly.

What I am doing is get the error as a callback and check if error is there disable submit button. but what is happening is when I type name required error is coming on the second letter is empty, one step backwards is happening. I link my code and screenshots with this post, thanks in advance :)

1. This is "index.js" file where we use this inputfield component

```js
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [error, setError] = useState(''); <
InputField
type = "name"
placeholder = "Enter your name"
label = "Name"
background = "black"
hover = "blue"
helper = "white"
value = {
  name
}
getError = {
  data => {
    setError(data);
  }
}
onChangeText = {
  text => {
    setName(text);
  }
}
/>
```

2. This is the input field component using formik and yup

```js
 const InputField = props => {
      const { type, placeholder, label, value, defaultValue } = { ...props };
      const handleChange = (event, error) => {
        const data = error === undefined ? '' : error;
        props.onChangeText(event.target.value);
        props.getError(data);
      };
    return (
        <Formik
          validateOnBlur
          validateOnChange
    
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            name: Yup.string()
              .required(' Name is required')
              .matches(/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/, 'Name cannot contain special 
               characters '),
    
           password: Yup.string()
              .required('Password is required')
              .min(6, 'Password must be at least 6 characters'),
            
          })}
        >
    <Fragment>
            <FormControl>
            <Field
                validateOnBlur
                validateOnChange
                name={type}
                render={({ field, form }) => {
                  return (
                    <div>
                      <TextField
                        name={type}
                        type={type}
                        placeholder={placeholder}
                        error={Boolean(form.errors[type] && form.touched[type])}
                        value={value}
                        margin="normal"
                        onChange={event => {
                          field.onChange(event);
                          handleChange(event, form.errors[type]);
                        }}
                        onBlur={event => {
                          field.onBlur(event);
                          props.getError(form.errors[type]);
                        }}
                      />
                      {type && form.errors && form.errors[type] && (
                        <Box color="error.main">{form.errors[type]}</Box>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  );}}/>
            </FormControl>
          </Fragment>
        </Formik>
      );
    };
```